# Google Glass add timeline item from companion app

Tags: google-glass, google-gdk

I have GDK app and companion app(which runs on mobile device) both paired via Bluetooth. Now I have to send notification to glass app(want to add new timeline item) from companion app. Is it possible? If so please share idea and some sample code.

Note: I want to implemet this feature without using Mirror API.
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently, the only way to add an item to the timeline is via the Mirror API.

Comment: This is correct. You can do a live card or create an activity (immersion, or full screen card, essentially), but there's no GDK method for creating a card in the timeline.